# Can you show continues speech-to-text on PyQt5 window?

Tags: python, azure, pyqt5, speech-to-text

I'm using Azure speech recognition and I want to create my own speech to text app and I want to show the text on PyQt5 window.

I still can't figure out how can I get the recognized text as an output to be displayed...

I got this code from another source and it was using tinkter to show the text on a window and I want to do the same thing

The source of the original code:
https://github.com/jimbobbennett/TwitchCaptioner/blob/master/captioner.py

This is the code of what I'm trying to do!
`

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
import math
import time

import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import config
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import SpeechConfig


def recognizing(args):
    global labelText

    labelText.set(args.result.text)

    resultReco = args.result.text

    print(resultReco)


def recognized(args):
    global f
    if args.result.text.strip() != '':
        f.write(args.result.text + "\n")


speech_key, service_region = "", ""  # key and service region goes here
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

result = speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(recognizing)
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized)
speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("WindowTitle")
layout = QVBoxLayout()
label = QLabel(result)
layout.addWidget(label)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

The output now!:
[image: The output now!]

update ..................................................................................................................................................................
I'm trying to go for another approach ...... I'm trying to implement one-shot recognition but I can't understand how to update the text in the label as I'm talking......

here is my code

```
import config
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time
import wave

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
import math

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import SpeechConfig

speech_key, service_region = "", ""  # speech key and region goes here
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)


def speech_to_Print():
    

    # section of code for audio input
   
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
    sentence = result.text  # register the text from speech into sentence field
    print(sentence)
    return sentence


class QRecognizer(QtCore.QObject):
    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, key, region, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=key, region=region)
        self._recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=config)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    speech_key, service_region = "", ""  # speech key and region goes here
    qrecognizer = QRecognizer(speech_key, service_region)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    while True:
        newSentence = speech_to_Print()
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(newSentence)

        qrecognizer.textChanged.connect(label.setText)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226911/discussion-on-question-by-user-fox-can-you-show-continues-speech-to-text-on-pyqt).

Comment: ok ..... I'm adding this comment so others know where I'm at and if possible can help...

I'm trying to go for the same approach but with one sentence text instead and using a while loop to continuously generate text...

I have tested the method and it gives me output in the console .... I'm only trying to make the label update but I can't understand how!

This is a code of how the text shows up <https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ucehugapuq.swift> .... I only want the PyQt5 window to update the text the same as the console does

Comment: Please if you want any clarification please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a new thread that will perform speech to text , you will then get the recognized text as a signal.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool, QObject, pyqtSignal
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from playsound import playsound

API_KEY = ""
REGION = ""


class Stt(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self) -> None:
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=API_KEY, region=REGION)
        speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)
        playsound('music/StartBeep.wav')
        result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
        playsound("music/EndBeep.wav")

        if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            self.signals.finished.emit(result.text)
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized")
        elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))

    def start(self):
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self)




    def start(self):
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self)


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal(str)
```

To start the recognition

```
stt=Stt()
stt.signals.finished.connect(callback_function)
stt.start()
```

Don't use same object for multiple recognition instead create a new one every time by wrapping above code in a function and calling that function.

I have written a detailed tutorial about how to use Azure Speech services in a PyQt5 app , please visit [this](https://anuragseven.github.io/using-azure-speech-in-a-pyqt5-app/) to read the tutorial , you can also get the complete code [here](https://github.com/anuragseven/azurespeech-pyqt5).